# Flow typechecking problems

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have Flow js error but cant understand what problem

Tried different utilities

```
class G{
    foo(){}}
class C{
    Bar(){}
}
const a: $ReadOnly<{+g: G, +c: C}> = {
    g: new G,
    c: new C,
}

type TT = $ObjMap<typeof a, <V>(_: V)=>V>;

function getProp<Generic: string>(propName: Generic): $ElementType<TT, Generic> {
    return a[propName]      
}

const c: G = getProp<'c'>('c');
```

Comment: https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEDiDeAoa0BmB7dAKAlPAvvoqJDAMJIoBCYATrgYkcOgHYQAu0YAXNACQAlAKZgAJgHlWIAJ4AeeAGoA5n1gAaaIuB8y+AHzQAvNErRV0VsIDucdcmg7LN6GXtFEHGQAdh0ACr+xgISAEYAVgCyYN5yXr7oqNyacgBq+lgA+nypOEb66QDcDiiIqACurMAcAJZs5sIcAAq06LGwwla0NU6c3azKGd6t3gByYAC2wmqdwt3AOHz8AKIgwlOsHP4+wnKBmh1dPYZIAJC0jeW0rNwA2sNt41MAuihv0EwlHyzsXE6wwWUjRabTkAHJgGCMhCwThCkA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it happens because of type missmatching. Just set right type.

`const c: C = getProp<'c'>('c');`

Comment: But i got another problem, may be you know the desicion?
https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEDiDeAoa0BmB7dAKAlPAvvoqJDAMJIoBCYATrgYkcOgHYQAu0YAXNACQAlAKZgAJgHlWIAJ4AeeAGoA5n1gAaaIuB8y+AHzQAvNErRV0VsIDucdcmg7LN6GXtFEHGQAdh0ACr+xgISAEYAVgCyYN5yXr7oqNyacgBq+lgA+nypOEb66QDcnj5+-gDSwjIwJvyV1XGlidz6iIioAK6swBwAlmzmwhwACrTosbDCVrS9ThVVEBneY94AcmAAtsJqU8IzwDh8-ACiIMJbrBz+pXKBmpPTs4ZIAJC0Qx20rNwA2svj6y2AF0UKDoExiGxOI5dMFlENRuM5AByYDIjKo5E4QpAA